# How to join two tables to replace a TSQL loop?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to join two tables in a special way. Currently the join is done with a cursor and a loop and I'm looking for a more efficient method to process the data.

The first table is a list of todo items:

```
create table todo
( todo_id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
  cnt int not null,      -- how many units of work have to be completed?
  work char(1) not null  -- type of work, for example 'x', 'y', 'z'
);
```

for example the table contains the following values

```
insert into todo (cnt, work) values (1, 'x'), (3, 'y'), (2, 'u'), (3, 'v'), (1, 'w');
```

this means work 'x' has to be completed once, work 'y' three times and so on. The work in this todo table has to be completed by the same worker in the Jobs table for the first 'available' Job_id. Each entry in the todo table leads to 'cnt' entries in the Jobs table.

```
create table jobs
(job_id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
 worker char(1) not null, -- name of worker, for example 'A', 'B', 'C'
 work char(1)
);
```

The Jobs table is filled initially with the following values:

```
insert into jobs (worker) values 
('A'),('B'),('C'),('A'),('C'),('B'),('A'),('B'),('C'),('A'),('B'),('C');
```

In the order of todo_id for each row in the todo table I do the following:

1. pick cnt and work
2. in the order of Job_id I search the first available worker from the Jobs table
3. update the Jobs tables cnt times with the work for the worker

I currently use the following T-SQL code to complete this task:

```
DECLARE @Cnt int, @work char(1);
DECLARE @Worker char(1);
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
  SELECT cnt, work from todo
OPEN myCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @cnt, @work
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
  select top 1 @Worker=Worker from jobs where work is null;
  update top(@cnt) j
  set work=@work
  from jobs j
  where j.work is null and j.worker=@worker;
  FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @cnt, @work
END
CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

todo table:

[image: todo Table]

resulting jobs table:

[image: resulting jobs table]

I'm looking now for an efficient query or update Statement that replaces the above loop and I currently can't think of a way to replace the above behaviour of the loop properly.

Comment: Why the available "workers" are not in order list? What if a "worker" starts a "job" which needs several iterations but in the jobs table it has fewer entries?

Comment: @gotqn: the Jobs table is precalculated, it is certain that it is much larger than what the todo list can feed. In my real world Project the Job_id is in fact time based and a worker is a machine that has to do things at a certain time. But for the sake of simplicity I changed the tables a bit.

Comment: I think the difficulty is here that the (planned) grouping of work does not match the grouping of worker.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your cursor in a while loop, it may perform better:

```
-->Variable Declarations
declare @minIterator int ,@maxIterator int,@outerIterator int, @outerLoopCounter int=0, @innerIterator int, @innerLoopCounter int=1, @worker char(1);
-->Max todo id
select @maxIterator = max(todo_id) from todo;
-->Min todo_id
select @minIterator = min(todo_id) from todo;
-->Number of times outer loop needs to execute
select @outerIterator = @maxIterator-@minIterator;


 -->Outer Loop for todo items
  while @OuterLoopCounter<=@outerIterator
   begin
    -->Set number of time innerLoop iterates
    select @innerIterator = cnt from todo where todo_id=@minIterator;
    -->Set worker to do the job 
    select   @worker = worker from jobs where job_id=(select min(job_id) from jobs where work is null)
  -->Inner Loop for count of each todo item
    while @innerLoopCounter<=@innerIterator
      begin
        update j
            set j.work=t.work
        from 
            jobs j,
            todo t 
        where 
            t.todo_id=@minIterator
            and j.job_id=(select min(x.job_id) from jobs x where x.work is null and x.worker=@worker);
        set @innerLoopCounter=@innerLoopCounter+1;
      end
   set @innerLoopCounter=1;
   set @outerLoopCounter=@outerLoopCounter+1;
   set @minIterator = @minIterator+1;
  end


-->See Results
select * from jobs
```